# Find the cardinality of $\big\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2= 2^{2018}, xyz\in\mathbb{Z} \big\}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, diophantine-equations, cardinals

> What is the cardinality of set $\big\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2= 2^{2018},    xyz\in\mathbb{Z} \big\}$?

Since I have very limited knowledge in number theory, I tried using logarithms and then manipulating the equation so that we get $$10^{2018}+2=x^2+y^2+z^2.$$
Then setting one of $x,y,z$ equal to $\sqrt{2}$ we find all values of $x$ and $y$ where  $$2x^2+y^2=10^{2018}.$$
Finally we use combinatorics to get the required answer.
However this led to no-where.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you edit the question? There seems to be a typo.

Comment: this is more of counting the number of solutions to a diophentine equation, not set theory. There is a similar qn: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer

Comment: @AnuragA I have made the edit

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: I added my work , although i think it is incorrect

Comment: @RadialArmSaw huh? that is a set.

Comment: In the definition of the set at the beginning of the question, is required that each of numbers $x$, $y$ , and $z$ belongs to $\Bbb Z$, or only their product?

Comment: @mathworker21 It is a set of ordered triplets?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw yes....

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear.  I shall consider two sets $$S:=\Big\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\,\Big|\,x^2+y^2+z^2=2^{2018}\Big\}$$
and
$$T:=\Big\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\,\Big|\,x^2+y^2+z^2=2^{2018}\text{ and }xyz\in\mathbb{Z}\Big\}\,.$$

To calculate $|S|$, note that $0$ and $1$ are the only residues modulo $4$.  Therefore, for any integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ if and only if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are even.  From this result, we conclude that, for any $(x,y,z)\in S$, $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$, and $z=2z_1$ for some integers $x_1$, $y_1$, and $z_1$.  Note that $$x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=2^{2016}\,.$$
For a positive integer $k<1009$, suppose that $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$ has been defined with $$x_k^2+y_k^2+z_k^2=2^{2(1009-k)}\,.$$
By the same argument, there exist integers $x_{k+1}$, $y_{k+1}$, and $z_{k+1}$ such that $x_k=2x_{k+1}$, $y_k=2y_{k+1}$, and $z_k=2z_{k+1}$.  That is, $$x_{k+1}^2+y_{k+1}^2+z_{k+1}^2=2^{2(1008-k)}=2^{2\big(1009-(k+1)\big)}\,.$$
By induction, we see that
$$x=2^{1009}x_{1009}\,,\,\,y=2^{1009}y_{1009}\,,\text{ and }z=2^{1009}z_{1009}\,,$$
with
$$x_{1009}^2+y_{1009}^2+z_{1009}^2=1\,.$$
Thus, there are only six possible choices for $(x_{1009},y_{1009},z_{1009})$, namely
$$(\pm 1,0,0)\,,\,\,(0,\pm1,0)\,,\text{ and }(0,0,\pm 1)\,.$$
Ergo, $S$ contains $6$ elements:
$$\left(\pm 2^{1009},0,0\right)\,,\,\,\left(0,\pm2^{1009},0\right)\,,\text{ and }\left(0,0,\pm 2^{1009}\right)\,.$$
That is, $|S|=6$.

To calculate $|T|$, we shall prove that the polynomial
$$p(t):=t^3-t^2+\lambda t-\frac{1}{64}$$
has three distinct positive real roots $\alpha_\lambda$, $\beta_\lambda$, and $\gamma_\lambda$, for all real numbers $\lambda$ satisfying
$$0.232\leq \lambda\leq 0.282\,.\tag{*}$$  For a proof, note that the [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5Bt%5E3-t%5E2%2Bx*t-1%2F64%2Ct%5D) of $p(t)$ as a polynomial in $\lambda$ is
$$d(\lambda):=-4\lambda^3+\lambda^2+\frac{9}{32}\lambda-\frac{283}{4096}\,.$$  Using a [numerical software](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B-4t%5E3%2Bt%5E2%2B9%2F32*t-283%2F4096%3E0%2Ct%5D), we see that $d(\lambda)>0$ for all $\lambda$ satisfying (*).  Observe now that
$$(x,y,z):=\left(2^{1009}\sqrt{\alpha_\lambda},2^{1009}\sqrt{\beta_\lambda},2^{1009}\sqrt{\gamma_\lambda}\right)$$
satisfies
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2^{2018}\text{ and }xyz=\frac{2^{3\cdot 1009}}{\sqrt{64}}=2^{3024}\,.$$
This shows that $|T|\geq \mathfrak{c}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the continuum.  On the other hand, $|T|\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, making $|T|\leq \mathfrak{c}^3=\mathfrak{c}$.  That is, $|T|=\mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \in \mathbb N$, consider the equation

$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2^n $$

where $x,y,z$ are integers. Since $x \mapsto -x$, $y \mapsto -y$, $z \mapsto -z$ does not change the equation, we may assume $x,y,z \ge 0$. We may henceforth suppose $x \ge y \ge z$.

Note that there is no solution when $n=1$.

Suppose $n \ge 2$. Since $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is even, exactly one of $x,y,z$ is even, or all three are even. The first of these cases is ruled out since $a^2 \equiv 0\pmod{4}$ if $a$ is even and $a^2 \equiv 1\pmod{4}$ when $a$ is odd. Therefore, $x,y,z$ are all even.

Writing $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$, $z=2z_1$ gives

$$ x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 = 2^{n-2}. $$

If $n-2=1$, there is no solution. If $n-2 \ge 2$, we repeat the above argument to arrive at the equation

$$ x_m^2 + y_m^2 + z_m^2 = 2^e, $$

where $e=0\:\text{or}\:1$.

The only solution in the case $e=0$ is $x_m=1$, $y_m=z_m=0$. There is no solution in the case $e=1$. From $x=2x_1=2^2x_2=\ldots=2^mx_m$, etc., we get $x=2^m$ when $n=2m$ is even, and $y=z=0$. There is no solution when $n$ is odd.

We conclude that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2^n$ has no solution when $n$ is odd, and that the only solutions when $n$ is even are $(x,y,z)=\pm(2^{n/2},0,0)$, and its permutations, giving a total of six solutions. $\blacksquare$